# Need help learning Python with non thread safe code

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to work through a tutorial for Python 3.12.2.  I'm at the section where it tries to demonstrate non-thread safe code.  The tutorial said the following code would produce unpredictable results.  Well, for me it produced very predictable results.  The code is:

```
# when no thread synchronization used

from threading import Thread as Thread

def inc():
    global x
    for _ in range(1000000):
         x+=1
 
#global variable
x = 0
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    # creating threads
    threads = [Thread(target=inc) for _ in range(10)]

    # start the threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    #wait for the threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread. Join()

    print("Pass ", counter, "final value of x:", f"{x:,}")
    x = 0
    counter += 1
```

It produced the following output;

```
PS D:\PythonDev> python .\thread3a.py
Pass  0 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  1 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  2 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  3 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  4 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  5 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  6 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  7 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  8 final value of x: 10,000,000
Pass  9 final value of x: 10,000,000
PS D:\PythonDev>
```

I modified it to add the outer while loop so I would not have to run it from the command line over and over again.  According to the tutorial the expected result of each pass is supposed to be 10,000,000.  However, in reality the result should be unpredictable and less than 10,000,000.  It's neither.  What am I doing wrong?

My environment is;

```
O/S: MS Windows 10 Home 22H2
RAM: 16 GB
CPU: Intel Core I7-2860QM
Terminal Session: PowerShell 7.4.1
Python version: 3.12.2
```

Comment: Your tutorial is wrong.  Because of the way Python works, as long as you wait for all the threads to finish, each pass MUST produce 10,000,000.  Python has a "global interpreter lock" that means only one thread at a time can actually be running Python code.  There is no true asynchronous operation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: The tutorial is actually a book titled, “Python for Geeks” by Muhammad Asif published by Packt Publishing.  I’m working my way through chapter 7, “Multiprocessing, Multithreading, and Asynchronous Programming” in the section “Synchronizing threads” the creation of a “Race Condition”. Such would be created because multiple threads would be accessing the same global variable “x” without protection.  The original source code is listed below as opposed to my modified (played with) code above.

Comment: [code block]# thread3a.py when no thread synchronization used 
    
    from threading import Thread as Thread

    def inc():
        global x
        for _ in range(1000000):
            x+=1
    #global variabale
    x = 0

    # creating threads
    t1 = Thread(target=inc, name="Th 1")
    t2 = Thread(target=inc, name="Th 2")
    
    # start the threads
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    #wait for the threads
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print("final value of x :", x)

Comment: According to the book, “The expected value of x at the end of the execution is 2,000,000, which will not be observed in the console output. Every time we execute this program, we will get a different value of x that's a lot lower than 2,000,000. This is because of the race condition between the two threads.”
Whenever I run the code from the book or my modified version I get the expected value (2,000,000 or 10,000,000) on a consistent basis. The exact opposite of what the book says I should get.

Comment: About eight pages earlier the book does make reference to the GIL stating it, “is a mutex that allows only one thread to use the Python interpreter at a time and blocks all other threads. This is necessary to protect the reference count that is managed for each object in Python from garbage collection. Without such protection, the reference count can get corrupted if it's updated by multiple threads at the same time. The reason for this limitation is to protect the internal interpreter data structures and third-party C code that is not thread safe.”

Comment: This makes it seem like it is impossible to create the Race Condition this example is trying to demonstrate and is causing my confusion.
Apologies for the very long comment.

Comment: @TimRoberts I believe this time you are incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong.

Comment: Integer add is implemented in C. A class with a heftier add function would show the problem more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BooBoo stated "The tutorial is correct because the operation x += 1 is not atomic", but with a fast system it is a lot less likely to occur with threading.  Even increasing range to 100M I wasn't getting failures.  I was quite surprised actually...1B increments per pass and *never*??.  I used the following to explicitly slow down the incrementing operation by forcing a context switch between the read/modify/store operation to make a worst-case scenario:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

lock = Lock()

def inc():
    global x
    for _ in range(10000):
        #with lock:
            a = x         # capture current value
            time.sleep(0) # gives up time slice explicitly
            a += 1        # increment it
            x = a         # store it back in global.
```

Without the lock:

```
Pass  0 final value of x: 10,096
Pass  1 final value of x: 10,107
Pass  2 final value of x: 10,095
Pass  3 final value of x: 10,112
Pass  4 final value of x: 10,110
Pass  5 final value of x: 10,105
Pass  6 final value of x: 10,111
Pass  7 final value of x: 10,105
Pass  8 final value of x: 10,092
Pass  9 final value of x: 10,107
```

With the lock:

```
Pass  0 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  1 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  2 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  3 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  4 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  5 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  6 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  7 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  8 final value of x: 100,000
Pass  9 final value of x: 100,000
```

Comment: Thanks.  Adding your mods to inc() got it to work.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial is correct because the operation `x += 1` is not atomic; it consists of multiple Python byte-code operations (see offsets 12 through 18 below):

```py
>>> import dis
>>> def inc():
...     global x
...     for _ in range(1000000):
...          x+=1
...
>>> dis.dis(inc)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                12 (to 22)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (_)

  4          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             16 INPLACE_ADD
             18 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (x)
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) the threads cannot execute their byte code in parallel. Consequently, since each thread is not doing any I/O or network activity that would cause it to release the GIL and allow another thread to execute, the thread will execute its byte code until its time slice is up. Now if the computer you are running on is "fast", it can execute all 1,000,000 iterations of its loop within a single time slice. My computer is seemingly not "fast" and when I run your code (after replacing `thread. Join()` with `thread.join()`) I get:

```None
Pass  0 final value of x: 6,688,134
Pass  1 final value of x: 6,096,719
Pass  2 final value of x: 6,250,393
Pass  3 final value of x: 6,116,210
Pass  4 final value of x: 6,686,225
Pass  5 final value of x: 4,912,244
Pass  6 final value of x: 4,965,819
Pass  7 final value of x: 6,301,143
Pass  8 final value of x: 6,549,947
Pass  9 final value of x: 7,321,995
```

This is because each thread is getting interrupted at arbitrary points in its code and if the byte code gets interrupted in the middle of executing `x += 1`, then the results will be less than 10,000,000 (you should be able to figure out why). If, however, I reduce the number of iterations down to only 100,000, then a single time slice is sufficient and I do get a result of 1,000,000 for each pass. Try increasing the number of iterations continuously by a factor of 10 until you see the problem manifest itself.

If you have instead ...

```py
from threading import Thread as Thread, Lock

lock = Lock()

def inc():
    global x
    for _ in range(1000000):
        with lock:
            x+=1

...
```

... you will get 10,000,000 for each iteration -- **but the code runs much more slowly.**

Comment: Dammed Microsoft Editor: Spelling & Grammar Checker extension.  It keeps throwing in a space and capital letter after a period when I'm not looking.

Comment: Is this in reference to `thread. Join()`? Don't you just copy and paste from *running* code? Anyway, if my post satisfactorily answers your question, then consider *accepting* it.

Comment: The reference is indeed to thread. Join().  Even though I cut 'n pasted the running code, when I used the up or down arrow to scroll through the entire comment, the editor decided to modify the text as if it was a sentence instead of code.  I caught it in a few places.  Missed that one.

Comment: I found your response very interesting as I have not had a chance to delve into the disassembler for Python bytecode.  Didn't even know it existed.  Cool stuff.  Gave it an up vote.  And the next section of the tutorial talks about locks.  However the code didn't start working properly (incorrectly?) until I added the sleep(0) statement from Mark Tolonen's answer below.